# Messed Up OpenGL Depth Buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, blackberry-playbook

I have something rather strange going on at the moment with my code. I am running this on a BlackBerry Playbook and it is OpenGL ES 1.1

EDIT 4: I deleted everything I have posted to simplify my question.

I took the code and simplified it to drawing two overlapping triangles. Here is the array containing the coordinates as well as an array containing colours:

```
GLfloat vertices[] =
{
          // front
           175.0f, 200.0f, -24.0f,
           225.0f, 200.0f, -24.0f,
           225.0f, 250.0f, -24.0f,

          // back
           200.0f, 200.0f, -25.0f,
           250.0f, 200.0f, -25.0f,
           250.0f, 250.0f, -25.0f
};


static const GLfloat colors[] =
{
       /* front  */  1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f, //Red
       /* back  */  0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f //Green
};
```

Please note that my coordinates are 0 to 1024 in the x direction and 0 to 600 in the y direction as well as 0 to -10000 in the z direction.

Here is my setup code which reflects this:

```
    glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glViewport(0, 0, surface_width, surface_height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrthof(0, surface_width, 0, surface_height, 0, 10000);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
```

I have depth enabling in two places as I was trying to rule out the possibility that it was supposed to be used while a certain matrix mode was chosen.

Lastly here is my render code:

```
void render()
{
    //Typical render pass
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0 , 6);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    //Use utility code to update the screen
    bbutil_swap();
}
```

The issue is that no matter what I do the green triangle is always overlayed over the red one. Changing z values either way has no effect on the finished image. I cannot figure this out.

Comment: This code is too huge for what you ask. Try to reduce it while leaving the essense of your question.

Comment: The code is just in case it helps. Most of it is just triangle vertices and colours or commented out. My question is why some colours seem to be thrown to the front of the depth buffer rather than the actual position of the face to which they have been applied.

Comment: On second thought I will re-edit this when I get anything simpler working.

Comment: Not related to you problem: you undo the translate after the glDrawArrays command. You can use glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix commands to temporary change the matrix and afterwards restore the old state.

Comment: @kakTuZ In general, yes. But in his case he still has the roation in there, so it's not the same (if this is inteded is another question, though).

Comment: Simplified the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it to work. The issue was with EGL setup code that I used that was provided. In bbutil.c (in my case .cpp) there is some code:

```
if(!eglChooseConfig(egl_disp, attrib_list, &egl_conf, 1, &num_configs)) {
        bbutil_terminate();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

(that is not all the code in the file but its the important bit)

This basically freaks if the given attribute list is nor supported. Up higher in the file attrib_list is set as follows:

```
EGLint attrib_list[]= { EGL_RED_SIZE,        8,
                        EGL_GREEN_SIZE,      8,
                        EGL_BLUE_SIZE,       8,
                        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,    EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
                        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 0,
                        EGL_NONE};
```

There is no depth buffer specified. Now if you look in the EGL spec it says no depth is the default. BINGO, that's the problem. So I just modified it to look like this:

```
EGLint attrib_list[]= { EGL_RED_SIZE,        8,
                        EGL_GREEN_SIZE,      8,
                        EGL_BLUE_SIZE,       8,
                        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,    EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
                        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 0,
                        EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24,
                        EGL_NONE};
```

Note the EGL_DEPTH_SIZE and the 24. This sets the depth buffer to 24 bits. On the PlayBook 32 throws a segmentation fault although usually 32 is not supported anyways. Perhaps this will help someone out there trying to figure out why the provided include is causing this funny result I described as my problem.

Answer (score 5):

By default, depth testing is disabled. You have to enable it with glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST). The reason why it is working when you enable culling is because the back facing triangles are not drawn, and since a cube is a convex polyhedron, no front-facing quad will ever overlap another front-facing quad. If you try to render a second cube, however, you will see depth problems as well, unless you enable depth testing.

Comment: I should have said that I tried that without any success but this is still a good answer. I am begging to think that the windowing API gave me a buffer with no depth or something. Is that possible? Is this enough to enable depth within openGL?
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);